# Notice: Constant BASEURL already defined

Tags: php, html

I wanted to change the code so that when I click on profile in navigation it would return either the `profiled.php` page for doctor and `profilep.php` page for patient depending on whether a result is returned from `sql statement` after checking if the username from session is present in the patient table.

This is my code,

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM patients WHERE username='$username'";
$result=$db->query($sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) { ?>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="ecom.php" class="navbar-brand" style="color:white">MedAssist</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" style="color:white">Appointments</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Medicine Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="profiled.php" style="color:white">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="logoutd.php" style="color:white"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav> <?php;
}
else {
    ?>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="ecom.php" class="navbar-brand" style="color:white">MedAssist</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" style="color:white">Appointments</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Medicine Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="profilep.php" style="color:white">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="logoutp.php" style="color:white"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav> <?php; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Before adding the if-else statement everything was working fine but it would only return fixed navigation bar and the profile would point to one page (the profile of the doctor or patient). After adding the if-else statement I got 4 warnings and a notice:

```
Notice: Constant BASEURL already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\medassist\core\init.php on line 8
```

Comment: The errors and notice are generated because it does not find the file init.php at the specified location of ../core/init.php.  Make sure that file path is correct.

Comment: In your code, I don't find `BASEURL`. As per error, you are trying to define the `BASEURL` twice which is not correct. You just need to define it once. But in your code, there is no `BASEURL`.

Comment: Either you have added incomplete code or `BASEURL` define twice in `init.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

The constant `BASEURL` is defined in 2 different places. The notice telling you about it is output. Then when you attempt to session start it fails because of this output. Rectify the BASEURL issue and the session stuff will work.

EDIT: Ok I see the question has been modified, but the original error output you had in the question explains about the output already being sent.

Answer (score 0):

for warning session_start() : Move session start to the top and run again
then automatically your **3rd error** will be solved
and for 1st nb error check may be you reassigning any value or url in CONSTANT variable BASEURL